# image is not being displayed as intended

Tags: css, blazor, blazor-client-side

I am creating a Blazor app and my css is not being applied to the page.

I have included the CSS on the index.html page.

```
<div class="login100-more" style="background-image:url('images/bg.jpg');"></div>
<div class="wrap-login100 p-1-50 p-r-50 p-t-72 p-b-50"></div>
```

the css for this class

```
[ Login100 more ]*/
.login100-more {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: calc(100% - 520px);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.login100-more::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #e8519e;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #e8519e, #c77ff2);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #e8519e, #c77ff2);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #e8519e, #c77ff2);
  background: linear-gradient(bottom, #e8519e, #c77ff2);
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.wrap-login100 {
  width: 520px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: relative;
}
```

the p-?-50 is padding
l = left
r = right
t = top
b = bottom

when I view the html without Blazor, it looks fine.
when I move run it as a Blazor app, the image is missing!

sample code was downloaded from https://colorlib.com/wp/template/login-form-v13/

I modified the names of the fields to fit my needs. Other than renaming the text input, everything else was left the same

Comment: Can you please share a picture of the app structure?

Comment: Do you see any 404 errors in your network tab?

Comment: There are no 404 errors. What do you mean by App Structure?